# PHP Upload form giving out errors

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I,m a total PHP newbie, I learned about arrays yesterday and my boss asked me to write a PHP form, I found one on W3 schools and ended up with

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php 
$allowedEXTs = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end ($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"] ["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES ["file"] ["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES ["file"] ["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES ["file"] ["size"] < 10240)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
    if ($_FILES["file"] ["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $_Files["file"] ["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES ["file"] ["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES ["file"] ["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . $_FILES ["file"] ["size"] / 10240 . " kB<br>";
        echo "Stored in:" . $_FILES ["file"] ["tmp_name"];
    }
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
    {
        echo $_FILES ["file"] ["name"] . "already exists.";
    }
    else 
    {
        move_uploaded_files ($_FILES ["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES ["file"] ["name"]);
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

I basically don't know why this is throwing up "Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in" that error, can anyone lend a helping hand?

Comment: in `in_array()` isn't an array, so you get that error.

Comment: That worked so far, then this error came up Fatal error: Call to undefined function move_uploaded_files() in

Comment: That's because the function is `move_uploaded_file()`

Comment: I've changed that now and its telling me the file is there, BUT the FTP isn't showing it for some reason? Any ideas?

Comment: Stored in:/tmp/phphDNNWISL8549 thats where it SAYS it is, but for the life of me I cant find that

Comment: it should be in `upload/filename` (wherever you moved it to with `move_uploaded_file()`)

Comment: Now im getting: failed to open stream: operation failed in...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$allowedEXTs = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
```

Declared like this,

```
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
```

Called like this,

You have declared it with **"EXTs"** and calling it as **"Exts"**...
Hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

You define the array with

```
 $allowedEXTs = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
```

then call it with

```
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
```

Make sure the case is the same every time you call a variable.

---

Same with this line which should be `$_FILES`:

```
echo "Error: " . $_Files["file"] ["error"] . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare the array with $allowedEXTs, but it is spelled small in the if statement.